# Migrating from AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, mongodb

I have developed a  application using GWT/AppEngine/Objectify. There are many clients who want this locally deployed in their environments as the data is sensitive.
I cannot think of a way where the data of a application is hidden from its developers in AppEngine. Even I encrypt the data there will be always question about security.

I thought of the following alternatives

a) I have now a multitenancy application in appengine. I can now have a deployment for particular clients using their individual google accounts. This way they have security of data. I am not sure how I will handle new deployments. There is nothing like sharing the application with a user.

b) Migrate to MongoDB/MYSql.
This will lead to the whole question of handling migrations when data models are changed.I have read that with MongoDB I will not face migration issues. Is this correct.

What would be the best way to solve this issue. The root issue is that we as developers have access to data in Google/AppEngine environment which the client does not want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why migrate GAE now have a MongoDB-like API; you may want to try: https://github.com/mungo-appengine/mungo

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be for the client to create an App Engine account and you only supply the war.

If you still plan to migrate away from GAE, then you might want to take a look at [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) and [capedwarf-blue](https://github.com/alesj/capedwarf-blue).

Comment: I think this would be against the ToS - you can't have multiple applications serving the same purpose.  Maybe these purposes would be different enough?

Comment: @Riley - the developer would not have multiple apps/accounts. Each client would have it's own account - that's the main purpose of my suggestion: this way developer would not have access to clients data.

Comment: This model is fine, so long as each app is owned and managed by the relevant developer.

Comment: This is a problem not inherent to GAE: how do you develop and manage an app, yet do not have access to data. Quite impossibly imho. This is best solved with a proper contract.

Comment: @Nick - so what you are saying is a developer can not create a GAE app and ship it to their customers as a war, where each customer has it's own GAE account, owned & managed by themselves?

Comment: @PeterKnego Er, no, I was saying just the opposite. Doing that is fine.